# Canon 600 D on Adobe premiere

Tags: timelapse, canon-600d, adobe

I have an Canon 600D, i do many things with it, like timelapse, long exposure photos, etc..

My question is it possible to connect my Canon 600D an take pictures using capture of Adobe Premiere?

Comment: Do you really mean Adobe Premiere and not Adobe Photoshop Lightroom? Premiere is a tool for video.

Comment: Yes i mean Adobe Premiere, i know its used to edit video, but what i can understand its that adobe premiere can connect to external cameras and do video recording or take a picture.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Batch Capture feature in Adobe Premiere is for use with Firewire based camera control and video capture.  The 600D does not have a firewire connector and thus can not be used with Premiere's batch capture feature.  If you wish to do remote capture with your 600D you should connect via USB and use the Eos Utility software that came with your camera.